# VueJS and HTML table: How to hide certain keys and loop through the values?

Tags: vuejs2

In my Vue app, I have some JSON object data like so:

codesandbox available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/country-old-and-new-5uf8p?file=/src/App.vue:349-519

```
{
  "name": "Canada",
  "shortName": "CanadaEH",
  "shortName_old": "Canada",
  "fullName": "The NEW Republic of Canada",
  "fullName_old": "The Republic of Canada",
  "entryNotes": "Changed the short name and full name ",
  "entryNotes_old": "fixed typo on short name"
}
```

What I want to do is filter the object keys marked with `*_old`) and hide those keys from the table headings so that only the keys WITHOUT the `_old` will  be visible (ie, only show `shortName` and NOT `shortName_old`).

Howevever, I want to show both values from the `*_old` keys AND the ones without the `*_old` keys. I want to show them on the same `<td>` element.

Here's what it looks like now (what I dont' want to see):

[image]

Here is what I **want** to see:

[image]

In my attempt, I have the `v-for` on the table like so:

```
        <tr v-for="(value, keyName, index) in changes" :key="index">
          <th>
            {{ keyName }}
          </th>
          <td>{{ value }}</td>
        </tr>
```

And that gets the current output, but obviously not what I am trying to get. How can I write the code so I get what I am trying to achieve?

I have a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/country-old-and-new-5uf8p?file=/src/App.vue:349-519).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a computed property for that. Like this

```js
import Data from "@/assets/data.json";
export default {
  name: "App",
  computed: {
    changes() {
      const changes = { ...Data };

      for (const key in changes) {
        if (key.endsWith("_old")) {
          const newKey = key.slice(0, -"_old".length);
          changes[newKey] = `Old: ${changes[key]} / New: ${changes[newKey]}`;
          delete changes[key];
        }
      }

      return changes;
    },
  },
};
```

Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/country-old-and-new-forked-nioox?file=/src/App.vue:1425-1852).